# Que erro é esse net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED em php?

Tags: php, angularjs

Olá,
Estou tentando passar parâmetros para um arquivo php, email e senha, para uso de login pela seguinte url:"http://www.vigilantescomunitarios.com/php/login.php?ema=guga@guga.com&sen=12345" e o seguinte aviso aparece

> net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Seria os parâmetros que estão com problema? Pois quando executo a url na mão "http://vigilantescomunitarios.com/php/login.php" roda e claro, avisa que as duas variáveis estão indefinidas

> Notice: Undefined index: ema in /var/www/vigilantescomunitarios.com/public_html/www/php/login.php on line 17
>
> Notice: Undefined index: sen in /var/www/vigilantescomunitarios.com/public_html/www/php/login.php on line 18

Controller:

```
var ema = usuario.email;
var sen = usuario.senha;
$http.post("http://www.vigilantescomunitarios.com/php/login.php?ema="+ema+"&sen="+sen).success(function (response){
        console.log(response);
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,x-prototype-version,x-  requested-with');

include_once("conPDO.php");

$pdo = conectar();

$email = $_GET['ema'];
$senha = $_GET['sen'];
echo $email.' - '.$senha;
?>
```

Comment: O problema está no `www.`, não existe este subdomínio, por isso não pode achar o endereço. Se você acessar `http://vigilantescomunitarios.com/php/login.php?ema=guga@guga.com&sen=12345` (note: sem o `www.`!) ele irá carregar normalmente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que o site não possui o subdomínio `www.`. Por essa razão é mostrado erro de não encontrar o domínio, porque de fato não existe. Removendo o `www.` do URL não existirá o erro. ;)

**Solução:**

**Método 1 via Javascript:**

```
$http.post("http://vigilantescomunitarios.com/php/login.php?ema="+ema+"&sen="+sen).success(function (response){
        console.log(response);
}
```

> Simplesmente remova o `www.`.

Porém isso não resolve todo o problema!

**Método 2 via Apache:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

> Isto irá redirecionar o `http://www...` para o `http://...`

**Método 2 via Nginx:**

```
server {
    server_name www.vigilantescomunitarios.com;
    return 301 $scheme://vigilantescomunitarios.com$request_uri;
}
```

> Isto irá redirecionar o `http://www...` para o `http://...` ou `https://www...` para `https://...`.

Para realizar o Método 2 é preciso que configure o DNS, assim apontando o subdomínio e o domínio para o mesmo servidor.

Por exemplo:

[image: DigitalOcean]

Imagem e algumas informações foram extraídas [deste tutorial da DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-redirect-www-to-non-www-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04). O painel de configuração irá variar de DNS para DNS.

Comment: Pois é @Inkeliz, é que eu estou usando o serviço da DigitalOcean e eles me passaram os passo-a-passo para instalar e configurar tudo.
Depois te passo como está o apache2.conf.

Comment: Veja:

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin gustavo.msevero@gmail.com
        ServerName vigilantescomunitarios.com
        ServerAlias www.vigilantescomunitarios.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/vigilantescomunitarios.com/public_html/www
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>